# Enabling Cassandra Row Caching for a Specific Column Family

Tags: cassandra

I have a very small column family that is accessed like crazy and hardly ever written to.  I would like to enable row caching for just this one column family.

I'm having a hard time determining how to do this.  According, the comments section of [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/caching-in-cassandra-1-1) documentation, I can "enable / disable caching on a per CF basis."  How exactly do I accomplish that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I finally found it.

```
create column family my_column_family
with key_validation_class = 'CompositeType(LongType, DateType)'
and comparator = UTF8Type
and caching = 'ALL'
and column_metadata= [
{column_name: my_column_name_1, validation_class: BooleanType},
{column_name: my_column_name_2, validation_class: BooleanType}
];
```

Comment: how do I change this `caching` setting for an existing CF?

Comment: ALTER TABLE [table_name] WITH caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'ALL' } ;
You can set a value for rows_per_partition.